# How to insert a new row at top and bottom in HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, row

```
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>SL.No.</td>
                <td>First Name</td>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td>City</td>
                <td>Country</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>USA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jane</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>Los Angeles</td>
                <td>USA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Detroit</td>
                <td>USA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jane</td>
                <td>Smith</td>
                <td>Seattle</td>
                <td>USA</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Jack</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td>Las Vegas</td>
                <td>USA</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="data">
            <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name">
            <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
            <input type="text" id="city" placeholder="Enter City">
            <input type="text" id="country" placeholder="Enter Country">
            <button>Add row to bottom</button>
            <button>Add row to top</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
table {
    margin: 150px auto;
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table tbody tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table tbody tr td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
}
```

```
let btnAdd = document.querySelector('button');
let table = document.querySelector('table');

let firstNameInput = document.querySelector('#firstname');
let lastNameInput = document.querySelector('#lastname');
let cityInput = document.querySelector('#city');
let countryInput = document.querySelector('#country');

btnAdd.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let firstname = firstNameInput.value;
    let lastname = lastNameInput.value;
    let city = cityInput.value;
    let country = countryInput.value;

    let tableData = `
      <tr>
         <td>${firstname}</td>
         <td>${lastname}</td>
         <td>${city}</td>
         <td>${country}</td>
      </tr>
    `;

    table.innerHTML += tableData;
});
```

[image: Output]

> Need to add a new row at the top and bottom of the table.
> However, the SL.NO. should be automatically adjusted.
> I write the code for auto incremented the SL.No. by using CSS.
> But when I enter the data in input field it applies from SL.NO. the last column "Country" is empty.
> How to resolve this issue?
> Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### js

```js
function getInputs() {
    let firstNameInput = document.querySelector('#firstname')
    let lastNameInput = document.querySelector('#lastname');
    let cityInput = document.querySelector('#city');
    let countryInput = document.querySelector('#country');
    
    return {
        firstname: firstNameInput.value,
        lastname: lastNameInput.value,
        city: cityInput.value,
        country: countryInput.value,
    }
}

function add(bottom=true) {
    const inputs = getInputs();

    if (!inputs.firstname && !inputs.lastname && !inputs.city && !inputs.country)
        return;

    let tableData = `
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>${inputs.firstname}</td>
        <td>${inputs.lastname}</td>
        <td>${inputs.city}</td>
        <td>${inputs.country}</td>
    </tr>
    `;

    let table = document.querySelector('table');

    table.innerHTML = bottom ? table.innerHTML + tableData : tableData + table.innerHTML;
};
```

### html

```html
        <table>
            ...
        </table>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="data">
                ...
                <button onclick="add()">Add row to bottom</button>
                <button onclick="add(false)">Add row to top</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```